# loading image from filesystem google app engine

Tags: image, google-app-engine, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

Is it possible to use the google app engine python imaging library, from a python script, to load an image file from the local filesystem? Or must images be loaded from the datastore? I can successfully load a text file and display it's contents.

I am using google app engine with Python 2.7 and using the PIL imaging library. I am using PyCharm and Google App Engine Launcher on Mac OS X 10.8.2. I am using version 1.1.7 of PIL which I built from source.

I want to perform some manipulation upon an image (or images) before returning them in the response output of my python script.

When I use the `Image.image( filename=<filename> )` function, the error I get informs me that the filename must start with "/gs". Stepping into the `__init()__` method of the Image object shows me that `blobstore.create_gs_key()` is used to create a blobkey if I supply a filename to the Image constructor.

Because I have a fixed set of images that I wish to manipulate, I was hoping to avoid having to manually upload them into the datastore for retrieval.

My trivial application handler currently looks like this;

```
class ChallengeImageHandler( webapp2.RequestHandler ):
    def get(self):
        olifant = images.Image( filename='gs/challenge/C017.png' )
        logging.debug( "olifant.width=%d" % olifant.width );
        logging.debug( "olifant.height=%d" % olifant.height );
        self.response.headers[ 'Content-Type' ] = 'image/png'
        self.response.out.write( olifant )
        return
```

My app.yaml looks like this;

```
application: hello_world
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true


handlers:

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /.*
  script: main.application

- url: /software_development.html
  script: main.application

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: PIL
  version: latest
```

I understand that I could achieve the same result by serving the image statically, but once I have managed to successfully load the image, I wish to manipulate it before serving it up. I have deliberately placed the images that I wish to load from my application and not have served as static content by the google app engine web server in a separate directory than `/images`. They are located in a subdirectory called `gs/challenge`.

Any assistance, suggestions or solutions much appreciated. Perhaps I am going about this entirely the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load files from the local filesystem if you want just by uploading them along with your application.

As long as you realise that they will never change and you can't change them except when you deploy your application, and that there is a limit on the amount of space a deployed application can take up you should be OK.

For example, I upload a .csv file along with my application and when it starts up for the first time it reads it and creates a record in the datastore related to it's contents. I then never use that file again.

Where you place your images is not really relevant, as you are manipulating them before you serve them to the user they are not "static content" as such and won't be served to the user directly (as a .css file would be for example). As long as your application can load them that's the right place.

Comment: I do not agree. You can place your images in the blobstore and use Googles High Performance Images Serving with get_serving_url. This is not anly very fast, but also you do not have to serve the images yourself and it is almost for free. This is an example of a get_serving_url: https://lh6.ggpht.com/1HjICy6ju1e2GIg83L0qdliUBmPHUgKV8FP3QGK8Qf2pHVBfwkpO_V38ifAPm-9m20q_3ueZzdRCYQNyDE3pmA695iaLunjE=s0

Comment: I don't disagree with that all all, but the questioner seems to want to avoid, for some reason, putting this content in any kind of blobstore. Personally I would do as you suggest.

Comment: PaulC, thank you for your response. I am already able to load a text file and display it's contents. So I understand that it is possible to open/load a file within the app engine project. What I am having trouble doing specifically, is loading an image from the local file system. I am prepared to use the blobstore, just wondering if it was possible without that extra step.

Comment: Yes, there is no difference essentially between loading a text file from the local file system and any other type of file. What you have to do is load it internally to the application then serve it modified, as you seem to be doing.

Comment: Paul, I simply don't know how to instantiate the PIL Image constructor with a string of data read from an image file. The Image constructor which accepts a filename places restrictions on the filename and seems to be using the blobstore module to load the file. I have successfully loaded and rendered a text file. My question is; can one load an image from the local file system using the Imaging API available from google app engine. My apologies if my initial question was not specific enough.

Comment: Dear Paul, I agree with you. I can successfully load a file. What I haven't figured out is how to load a file into a PIL Image object so that I can manipulate it from the local filesystem on google app engine. I really appreciate that you responded to my question. I am going to be on a rural australian roadtrip without internet for the next week. So please forgive lack of responses over the next week. Rgds Dave Young.

Comment: "class Image(image_data=None, blob_key=None, filename=None)" so yes you can pass it a blob_key but it also accepts "image_data: The image data, as a bytestring (str). The image data can be encoded in JPEG, PNG, WEBP, GIF (including animated), BMP, TIFF, or ICO format." so perhaps pass it using image_data=your_data

Answer (score 0):

You were partly wrong/right,  I was finally able to open a file from memory using PIL this way, some of the imports might be unnecessary but w/e:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from io import BytesIO

rawdata = open(fullpathtoimagefile).read()
stream = BytesIO(rawdata)
im = Image.open(stream)
```